# WebRat page not loaded (you are being redirected)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrat

I have setup Webrat according to https://github.com/brynary/webrat

But when I want to:

```
"vist 'new'
```

then the "fill_in" method doesn't work.

This is because response.body has the contents:

```
"<html><body>You are being <a href=\"https://test.host/login\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
```

Can anyone tell why?

Answer (score 0):

The 'new' page requires authentication, so you're being redirected to the login page.  So you should either:

1. Remove authentication from the 'new' page
2. Use a sign_in helper to sign in the user before the body of the spec